# relationship between the sum of a matrix A's singular values and $max[trace(U^TAV)]$

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, singular-values

For a $m \times n$ matrix $A$, how to show $\Sigma_{k=1}^{r}\sigma_k(A) = max\{trace(U^T A V)\}$, where $U$ is m by r, V is n by r, and $U^TU = V^TV = I$? ( $\sigma_k(A)$ are the singular values of A )

From singular value decomposition, $A$ can be decomposed to some $U_2 \Sigma V_2^T$, however, the $U_2$ and $V_2$ are not necessarily same as the U and V before, both in terms of value and dimension. So how to prove that statement?

Comment: is this written right?

Comment: I'm also pretty certain that the dimensions of $U$ and $V$ are not correct.

Comment: And $A$ has to be quadratic, otherwise we can not compute the trace.

Comment: I'm not sure why the max is there but $A = U \Sigma V^{T}$ then  we have $U^{T} U \Sigma V^{T} V = \Sigma $ when we take the trace we get $\sum_{k=1}^{r} \sigma_{k}(A) $

Comment: also yeah the dimensions of $U, V$ are only for the truncated SVD but still work.

Comment: There's no problem with the dimensions of U and V, but I put the SVD result wrong (it should be $U \Sigma V^T$, will correct it in description). Note that the $U$ and $V$ in the SVD are not necessarily the same "$U$" and "$V$" in the former statement, so it's not simply plugging in the U and V.

Comment: then you should probably use different notation, no?

Comment: I think I put it quite clear in the description, but sure that would be better. I will edit it.